# Differenze tra 'emettibile', 'emanabile', 'emissibile'

Tags: word-choice

Quale ritenete sia corretto usare?

- il certificato è emettibile
- il certificato è emissibile
- il certificato è emanabile

Se più di loro sono corrette, qual è la differenza?

Comment: Un certificato si *rilascia*.

Comment: @egreg, maybe yes, ma prima di rilasciarlo non dovrebbe essere emesso? Cioè, come si fa a rilasciare un certificato che non è stato mai emesso?

Comment: Non capisco: *emettere* non riguarda un certificato. Un certificato può essere *steso* e *rilasciato*, non certo *emesso*.

Answer (score 6):

Emettibile deriva dall'infinito del latino *emittere*.
Emanabile deriva invece da un altro termine latino, *emanare*.
Il significato dei due non è molto distante, come puoi vedere consultando il Vocabolario Treccani alle voci [Emettere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/emettere/) ed [Emanare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/emanare/).

Emanare si dice prevalentemente di leggi ed ha un tono per così dire solenne, di solito si trova nella forma verbale non aggettivata:

> Sono stati emanati nuovi decreti

Emettere, oltre che in altri contesti, viene utilizzato nel linguaggio amministrativo come ad esempio:

> Non è possibile emettere certificati con fine prognosi antecedente la data di rilascio

Secondo me, nell'uso comune, con il tuo esempio, è più utilizzato il termine **rilasciare**:

> Il certificato è rilasciato

Emissibile non è un termine che ho mai sentito, seppure potrebbe essere una sostantivazione dell'aggettivo *[emissivo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/emissivo/)*.

Answer (score 5):

*Emissibile* is not in the Treccani dictionary, but I believe it can be regularly formed from *emettere*, like *ammissibile* from *ammettere*. However, in figured sense *emettere* is in phrases like

> *emettere un ordine, un provvedimento*, emanarlo; *emettere un mandato di pagamento*, renderlo esecutivo; *emettere azioni, obbligazioni, titoli di stato*, offrirli sul mercato; *emettere monete, biglietti, assegni*, metterli in circolazione.

*Emettibile* is not in the dictionary, either; however *mettibile* can be found (although not in the dictionaries I looked in).

*Emanare* has the same meaning of *emettere* when in the juridical sense, and also in proper sense, with perhaps only a slight difference: *emettere* might involve a precise direction, whereas *emanare* doesn't. *Emanabile* sounds bureaucratic: it makes little sense saying that *la sentenza è emanabile*.

A certificate is *rilasciato*, which is also bureaucratic. Probably in some code or regulations one can find something like *il certificato di residenza è rilasciabile dall'Ufficiale di Anagrafe* (with the proper uppercasing, of course), but a better Italian would be *l'ufficiale di anagrafe rilascia il certificato di residenza*.